# hasOwnProperty(propName) vs. hasOwnProperty("propName")

Tags: javascript

I've worked through the challenge at [Record Collection](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/record-collection) and have a working solution.

When and why do we add quotes (`""` or `''`) inside the `propName` for `hasOwnProperty(propName)`? When would you use `hasOwnProperty(propName)` or `hasOwnProperty("propName")`?

Here is my functioning solution:

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
 if (prop != "tracks" && value != "") {
   collection[id][prop] = value;
 }
else if (prop === "tracks" && collection[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") === false) {
 collection[id].tracks = [];
 collection[id].tracks.push(value);
}

 else if (prop ==="tracks" && value != ""){
   collection[id].tracks.push(value);
 }
else if (value === "") {
   delete collection[id][prop];
 }
  return collection;
}
```

but if `hasOwnProperty("tracks")` is changed to `hasOwnProperty(tracks)` the code stops working. This confuses me as the only example I was shown for `hasOwnProperty(propName)` did not use quotes, and fails if quotes are used around `propName`.

I learned about `hasOwnProperty()` from: [Testing object for Properties](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/testing-objects-for-properties).

Comment: the example you have linked does use quotes. The text in the description with literally `.hasOwnProperty(propname)` is just telling you what goes where, but it still should be a string. Say if before this you had defined propname like `var propname = "top";` it would work as you have described.

Answer (score 1):

In most situations, you want to be using a string to check if the property exists on the object. In cases where quotes aren't used, this would mean that it would have to be a variable which holds the value of a string corresponding to a property name - it has nothing to do with the variable being named the same way as the property. For example you may see some code like this where they iterate over the properties and check if the property belongs to the object (example taken from docs on [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)):

```js
var buz = {
  fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) { // here, name holds the value of the property
    console.log('this is fog (' + 
      name + ') for sure. Value: ' + buz[name]);
  }
  else {
    console.log(name); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

As @Gavin mentioned, the example shown is just trying to tell you that you can pass the name of the property as a string in place of `propname`

Comment: I think i understand now. When i wrote it as .hasOwnVariable(tracks) i was searching for a variable input named tracks, I believe it only works as .hasOwnVariable("tracks") because i was searching for a string (property) named tracks - i have no variable input named tracks to do anything with. Hopefully that's right, thanks for your help. they're two different options as i now understand it

Comment: @Ronan yup that's exactly it. Unless you have a variable holding the value of a property name, you probably want to be passing in a string of the property name, exactly as you described